# Ruby Associations - Many to Many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

could I have a review to see if I'm going in the right path? I'm working on a small project to make a digitalized snail mail type emulator, much like the Slowly app. The schema I've mocked up is here:

Main issue I'm having trouble solving is handling the associated across letters and inboxes. The inbox needs to hold the **user_ids of 2 users**.

The supposed logic is anytime the current user sends a letter to another user, this creates a unique instance of the **inbox** model that is accessible to both the sender and receiver.

**Schema for Letter and Inbox:**

```ruby
    create_table "inboxes", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.bigint "first_user_id", null: false
        t.bigint "second_user_id", null: false
        t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
        t.index ["first_user_id"], name: "index_inboxes_on_first_user_id"
        t.index ["second_user_id"], name: "index_inboxes_on_second_user_id"
      end
    
      create_table "letters", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer "sender_id"
        t.text "content"
        t.integer "inbox_id"
        t.time "delivery_time"
        t.string "subject"
        t.boolean "bottled"
        t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
      end
```

**User Model:**

```ruby
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
    
      has_many :letters, through: :inboxes
      has_many :inboxes
      has_many :hobbies, through: :hobby_tags
    
    end
```

The letter model will have the ID of the inbox created as well as subsequent letters to the same user so the inbox model will have a list of letters that all match its ID.

**Letter Model:**

```ruby
    class Letter < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :inbox
    end
```

**Inbox Model:**

```ruby
    class Inbox < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :first_user, class_name: 'User'
      belongs_to :second_user, class_name: 'User'
    end
```

Testing on Rails console, I'm having trouble creating a new letter model. When I pass in a user instance, the **sender_id** is *nil*, if I pass in a user.id into the letter it returns  the user ID but in both scenarios I'm unable to .save! it into the database since it flags that the User must exist.

**> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User must exist**

Answer (score 2):

If you're modeling snail mail it actually has a given direction to it (or else its never going to actually get anywhere) and the Inbox model isn't actually necessicary:

```
class Letter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender,     class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient,  class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sent_letters,
    class_name: 'Letter',
    foreign_key: :sender_id
  has_many :recieved_letters,
    class_name: 'Letter',
    foreign_key: :recipient_id
end
```

The "inbox" and "outbox" are actually just `user.recieved_letters` and `user.sent_letters`.

If what you want to model is actually more like a threaded conversion you could set it up like so:

```ruby
class Conversation
  has_many :messages
  has_many :users, through: :messages,
                   source: :sender
end

class Message
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'
end 

class User
  has_many :conversations
  # regardless of direction
  has_many :messages, 
    through: :conversations
  has_many :sent_messages,
    class_name: 'Message',
    foreign_key: :sender_id
  has_many :penpals,
    through: :conversations,
    source: :users
end
```

This is a much more flexible model that lets a conversation have any number of users.

Comment: Thats a very simplefied version of how you could model a conversation - where every user that has written a message in the conversation is "in the conversation". Typically you would add another join table between users and conversations so that user could leave or mute the conversation without doing so for all the other users.